# Flutter inkwell - how can I only proxy some specific event and pass other events?

Tags: flutter

I use Inkwell to add some effect, but this widget also listens to the onTap event. I don't want this; I only want it to listen to the onDoubleTap event, and then pass through the onTap event for the Accent Widget (a TabBar, default tap to switch tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an empty callback that does nothing:

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: ...
}
```

However, I would advise you to rethink this. If you show the ripple effect on tap, but nothing happens, your users will be very confused.

Comment: em, thank your answer, actually i'a like to add OnDoubleTap on TabBar item, but there is no propery i can pass when i looked source code, i found the TabBar widget Build method which wrapped child Widget with a InkWell Widget and only pass a OnTap method, i cant modify source code. so i have no idea

Comment: You can wrap your widget with a `GestureDetector` which has a `onDoubleTap` property.